# react-beautiful-dnd draggable not visible during drag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm creating a trello-like component using react-beautiful-dnd however the draggable object isn't visible during a drag and I am struggling to figure out why.

[See gif here](https://gfycat.com/GoodnaturedOptimalIndianjackal)

This is the relevant code: [here](https://pastebin.com/vCDcdw08)

I feel as though it might have something to do with

```
<Draggable
  draggableId={this.props.task.id}
  index={this.props.index}
>
  {(provided, snapshot) =>
    <div className={this.getClassName(snapshot.isDragging)}
      {...provided.draggableProps}
      ref={provided.innerRef}
      onClick={this.toggleDialog}
    >
      //etc
    </div>
  )}
</Draggable>
```

But I'm stumped

Answer (score 8):

This usually happens when there is a transform property (Example transform: scale(0.9)) in the parent components.

So, the default position property fixed doesn't work as expected.

So, we either have to remove the transform property wrapping the drag and drop component or just override the position property with static.

```
<div className={this.getClassName(snapshot.isDragging)}
  {...provided.draggableProps}
  ref={provided.innerRef}
  style={{ ...provided.draggableProps.style, position: 'static' }}
  onClick={this.toggleDialog}
>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This perfectly solves the painful problem which I've been facing for days. I was using transform and that was culprit. I have removed transform style because it's not important in my use case. Thanks for incredible answer which I didn't find any where